# Magento sets new session before timeout

Tags: php, magento, session, shopping-cart

I am trying to add product to cart in magento, so i am checking the Session checkout cart items, When i am adding the products are adding to cart and session also has the cart item.

When I am trying continuously, sometimes my session has empty cart, so i checked the session id by logging PHP's `session_id()` function.

When I receive my cart is empty even my cart had items, so i checked the log,so this time the `session_id()` logs `new_value` even my session is not timed out.

How can i resolve this problem?
**My Code:**

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($productId);
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
$this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Comment: could you provide the code you are running

Comment: @PixieMedia I have upadated my question with code.